# changing memory limit in ssh did not change

Tags: php, laravel, memory, composer-php, cpanel

I have try to install package and I got this error :

```
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Using version ^6.0 for laravel/passport
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Warning from https://repo.packagist.org: You are using an outdated version of Composer. Composer 2.0 is now available and you should upgrade. See https://getcomposer.org/2
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

mmap() failed: [12] Cannot allocate memory

Fatal error: Out of memory (allocated 808607744) (tried to allocate 20480 bytes) in phar:///opt/cpanel/composer/bin/composer/src/Composer/Repository/ComposerRepository.php on line 340
```

I have change memory limit in cpanel
when I check php.ini I have the new value for memory limit
but when I run this command

```
php -i | grep "memory_limit"
```

I got the old value

How can I change it?

Comment: What have you tried to debug the problem? Running `composer install` on any other than your own system should not be done after all, and `laravel/passport` in v6 is horribly outdated

Comment: it is v7 I run in

Comment: Please share more details by editing your question. Also, the given output shows that you try to install v6 of `laravel/passport`